# How to save date only from WPF datepicker using c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, date, visual-studio-2012, datepicker

I wanted to save only date in my database. There is a table which holds dates in database and the column which holds date in type of "Date". Now I want to store date from UI,so I placed WPF DatePicker in UI which allows to select date, but whenever I try to get the data from datepicker it shows the date and time.But I want just the dates to be stored in database.

[image: Code:I can t show actual code though]

This is the thing i am doing. It is demo code by the way. Can t upload original code. But this explains the thing. you can see in the message box, it shows 14-10-2015 00:00:00 , i want this zeros to be removed.

Comment: You should include actual code inside code-tags here, not a screen dump showing just text.

Comment: I think you have to look after this method of DateTime "ToShortDateString()"

Comment: i tried ToShortDateString();
1) var dateonly = date1.selectedate.value.date.ToShortDateString();
2) in dateonly variable i get "string" type date.
3) if i need to insert date in database, i will need date type.
4) when you convert string to date, you will have this format ==> 13-04-2015 00:00:00    !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The dateTime Picker has a property `DisplayDate` of Type `DateTime`. This type contains date **and** time information.

Just use `picker.DisplayDate.Date` this returns a `DateTime` value with the `TimeOfDay` component set to `00:00.00`

---

**Edit**

Usually you use an SQL Statement to insert or update values in the database. You should use a parametrized SQL statement with an parameter of type DateTime. The SQL API will take care of the conversion form `DateTime` (.Net type) to your SQL `Date` type and strip all time information away. It is a good idea to set the time component to 00:00:00 however to avoid any strange "roundings".

Comment: I found this in MSDN. The problem is how to save this in database, as the format remains like 13-04-2015 00:00:00, the later part which is zeroed. But i need to have only date, that can be saved in database. I would like to have only date. No time. Not even zeroed. Because database only accepts date!!

Comment: Please show the code where you set the date value in the database.

Comment: Added screen shot in actual question.

Comment: I am using LINQ to find any date in dateTable. Like this.
var demolinq = (from d in context.dates where d.date1 == finaldate select d.dateid).tolist();

Context is my database context(Entity Framework Database first),
date1 is actual date column in database,
dateid is primary key(int32) in dateTable,
finaldate is variable which holds date from date picker.

Comment: So what do you get if you read the Date back from the database?

Comment: Actually i cant query database and store. The data i received is date:time while the data i am having in database is only date. I need to save only those dates which are not available in database. So what i do is i use LINQ query to select dates and store new date only is that date is not available in that table. I cannot do this as it is not able to compare datetime data with date and returns always null.

Comment: Sounds like your actual problem is quite different from your question as stated above. Please update your question. (Or submit a new question)

Answer (score 0):

Use ToShortDateString() at the end something like:

```
var date = datePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();
            MessageBox.Show(date.ToString());
```